# Is there a way send email dynamically from email list table through Qlik Nprinting

Tags: qliksense

I am working on requirements, where I have created a flat table in qlik sense frontend, and table is as below:

| Email To | Email CC | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc@mail.com | xyz@mail.com | stopped |
| pqr@mail.com | aaa@mail.com | error at Line 2 |

As I have the table I need to send emails to those users whose emails are in the Email To column and keep them in the cc those emails are in Email CC and need to keep status in body.

Need to do this through NPrinting. This table's records change every hour. Everything needs to be done dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

No and yes...

No in that there's no built-in simple way of doing this for NPrinting (although there was in much older versions of NPrinting 16 for QlikView and there is in the new Tabular Reporting for Qlik Sense SaaS).

Yes in that there is a workaround that I've implemented a few places. You have one NPrinting report that takes this table and outputs it in the recipient format for NPrinting. See [this page](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/nprinting/Content/NPrinting/DeployingQVNprinting/Import-Users-Filters.htm) for details of the format. Make sure to add users to a group as part of this.

Then import the output of this using a Recipient Import Task. See [this page](https://community.qlik.com/t5/Official-Support-Articles/How-to-create-an-Qlik-NPrinting-Recipient-import-task-to-import/ta-p/1817720) for an example. You'll have to figure out what settings work for your situation - do you want to add/replace/update users to get the outcome you need.

Then, finally, you can have a Report Task that sends the actual report to users of the group you added the users to.

There are other ways - like using the NPrinting API as per [this example](https://community.qlik.com/t5/Qlik-NPrinting/NPrinting-dynamic-email-recipients-list-from-report/td-p/1630284).